# How to Compare the Data Distribution of 2 datasets?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, python, dataset, scipy

I'm having trouble to understand how to **compare** 2 sets of data by their **distribution** .

For Example,
how can I understand that column X100 has the same distribution as column Y1?

[image]

[image]

Also, is there a way to express the **distribution comparison** of all columns to all columns?

I'm a machine learning developer using **python**, and this is a part of a **classification problem** I'm working on.

Would appreciate any help.. tnx :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can compare distribution of the two columns using two-sample [Kolmogorov-Smirnov test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test), it is included in the `scipy.stats`: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.ks_2samp.html

From the [stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10884668/two-sample-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-python-scipy):

```
from scipy.stats import ks_2samp
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123456)
x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
y = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
z = np.random.normal(1.1, 0.9, 1000)

>>> ks_2samp(x, y)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.022999999999999909, pvalue=0.95189016804849647)
>>> ks_2samp(x, z)
Ks_2sampResult(statistic=0.41800000000000004, pvalue=3.7081494119242173e-77)
```

Under the null hypothesis the two distributions are identical. If the K-S statistic is small or the p-value is high (greater than the significance level, say 5%), then we cannot reject the hypothesis that the distributions of the two samples are the same. Conversely, we can reject the null hypothesis if the p-value is low.

Comment: which quantity to check specifically? statistic or p-value? sometimes I get KstestResult(statistic=0.291, pvalue=0.3095011576244957). Here, statistic is not too high and p-value is low. Should I reject null hypothesis based on p-value or accept based on statistic

Comment: @Vinay I worded it wrongly there, it's not an exclusive `or`. You look at p-value to judge how extreme the statistic (which is the "distance" between two distributions here) is. So if p-value is less than 0.05 it means you reject the null hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

To compare all columns to all columns, maybe you can create a response label column with "1" as data from dataset 1 and "0" as data from dataset 2. You can build a classification task over this response label using all columns in the combined dataset. If you can get a good AUC score, then the data is separable and the dataset 1 and dataset 2 are probably from two different distributions.