# How to compare two datasets and understand if they are part of the same population?

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

I have two datasets "theoretically" collected from the same engine.
I would like to merge these two datasets in order to train a single machine learning model; before doing this I want to be sure that I am not mixing two different things.

Right now I compared min, max, mean and std dev of each variable but this analysis seems a bit trivial.
Can you suggest me some statistic test or some procedure to confirm that the two datasets are collected from the same population and I can merge them?
Thank you :)

Comment: Why do you not know if the observations are collected from the same engine? // It might be preferable to include some other variable that considers the points to be different in some way (perhaps the car in which the engine is placed, for example, if you took an engine out of a red Ford Fiesta and put it in a blue Ford Fiesta).

Comment: I have been told that the engine is the same and the operating condition are "almost the same": I have been told there is some differences that should not affect my analysis. 
Since who collects data has not data skills, I have some doubts about the "almost the same" part :)

Comment: A similar question was answered [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/354035/how-to-compare-the-data-distribution-of-2-datasets) with a code example in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes graphical displays give clues about important
differences that formal tests do not.

Consider the following two samples from different distributions, but with similar means and standard deviations.

```
set.seed(906)
x1 = rgamma(1000, 4, .1)
mean(x1);  sd(x1)
[1] 39.79927
[1] 19.58579
x2 = rnorm(1000, 40, 20)
mean(x2);  sd(x2)
[1] 39.23941
[1] 19.78541
```

Boxplots show that the normal sample (top) takes negative values, while the gamma sample does not.

```
boxplot(x1, x2, col="skyblue2", horizontal=T, pch=20)
```

[image]

In this example a two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test that the two samples are from the same population rejects at the 5% level.

```
ks.test(x1, x2)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  x1 and x2
D = 0.064, p-value = 0.03328
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Empirical CDF (ECDF) plots look somewhat similar, but do show that the normal sample (blue) takes negative values. The K-S statistic $D$
is the maximum vertical distance between the two plots.

```
plot(ecdf(x1))
lines(ecdf(x2), col="blue")
```

[image]

It is not surprising that a Welch 2-sample t test fails to find
a difference between means and that a 2-sample F test fails to find a difference between variances. (There are no differences to be found in either test, and both tests assume both samples are normal.)

```
t.test(x1, x2)$p.val
[1] 0.5248905
var.test(x1, x2)$p.val
[1] 0.7486433
```

Moreover, smaller samples from the same two distributions are
not detected as different by the K-S test, while boxplots
hint that the distributions are not the same. [The two-sample K-S test is not known for excellent power.]

```
set.seed(2021)
y1 = rgamma(100, 4, .1)
y2 = rnorm(100, 40, 20)
ks.test(y1,y2)$p.val 
[1] 0.05410262
```

[image]

Also, the K-S test had trouble distinguishing between
two samples of a thousand observations from a gamma distribution
with shape parameter 6 and a normal population with matching
means and standard deviations. [Not shown.] A gamma distribution with shape parameter 6 is somewhat less skewed than one with shape parameter 4.